# Long break application got cut short after approval

Tags: human-resources

Got seriously tired of work, and thinking I needed a break, so I asked my supervisor (which is also a co-founder) if it is possible to take a month-long break at the end of the year. It was a brief discussion, and he checked and said it is OK, so I submitted the formal leave application formally after that at the beginning of the month.

So it got approved, but then the HR decided the whole break would be unpaid, which I am fine with it. However with 7 days left over, I was instructed to clear them off before the break or risk losing them. So I went to talk again with my supervisor in case that would affect any project he has for me in mind.

Then just an hour ago, I was called in only to be told that they want me to revise leave application to shorten it to two weeks. I was asked to write to the director if I insist of taking the month-long leave (at this rate I don't care if it is paid, unpaid, or whatever). I really don't feel like telling them "I got burnt out from my job, and really couldn't contribute much until I get some rest in between because I have tried all the possible ways to improve the project but nothing happens.".

My original alternative plan if my supervisor said no during the first discussion was to tender a resignation, because it would be a waste of time for both of us. However, now that I am stuck in between, I would probably sound/look like a really selfish/self-centered person if I have to resign over this.

**Should I try sending the letter to the director, and hope for the rest? What should I write? Or shall I just resign straight away?**

Some relevant info, this is my second time working with my supervisor (and some of the co-workers, they are great). I got offered this job (it sounded interesting when I took the offer) when he knew I was having difficulty finding a job that I wanted. I really don't want to be the bad guy here.

Comment: And what reason they gave you for shortening your already approved leave? Did you speak with your manager after submitting original application? It kind of looks like they have never dealt with that long break and don't have any processes in place to guide them. In that case, just keep your manager informed and do whatever they require you to do to keep things going forward.

Comment: "*However with 7 days left over, I was instructed to clear them off before the break or risk losing them.*" They wanted you take 7 additional days' leave in advance of your month-long holiday? // Could you clarify your core goal? I assume that's being able to take a full 4 week holiday to disconnect from work? // Could you clarify what country you're in?

Comment: @MirosławZalewski yea, my supervisor was there (he is the CTO if it is relevant) during the last discussion, the reason was the HR couldn't handle that partly due to taxation and stuff (mostly paper work from what I heard), which I find unreasonable (but I didn't say that in the discussion, just kept quiet because was totally unprepared for that discussion and was in shock).

Comment: @Lilienthal yes, previously I was told to clear them off before the month-long break. I needed a break from work because I am sick of it and couldn't contribute much to it anymore for now. Yes, a full month off. I would rather not tell where I am from.

Comment: @idesperatelyneedabreak We don't need a specific location but specifying the country would help narrow down your options. In the US your request would be much strangers and harder to sell than in the EU for instance. Your question has been put on hold and you should include some of the info you provided here in an [edit] and identify your core question, which should be something practical ("How do I respond if I want to do X", "How can I convince X to do Y").

Comment: Nah, I made my decision already, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The leave was approved and you made plans. It is perfectly fine for you to expect that you can take it.

If you want to go the official route, just state that you already made a lot of plans and it would also affect other people if you cancel now. No need to tell them any private things. I also think it is really wrong you should write to the director. If you have a superior who is responsible for approving your leave requests, he should stand up for his decision, not you.

Of course the whole thing seems to only add to an already not-so-great work situation. It is certainly okay do decide, at any point, that this job is no longer the right one for you, an to hand in your resignation. You don´t have to ground it on the whole leave-incident.

If you have a good relationship with one of your superiors, you could try to have a honest talk with him, although this could just as well backfire. But still, the worst thing that could happen is you loose your job, which you where thinking about anyways.

Comment: While I do not have a concrete plan (because they kept telling me different things about the application), I do have some rough idea on what to do. I honestly told them during the last discussion that I have not planned anything. Yea, I really don't think writing to the director is a good thing after giving it some thought. I don't see any point doing further discussion on this anymore and prolly gonna just tender my resignation anyway. Dragging this issue any further would definitely severe the relationship between my supervisor and I (he taught me a lot of things and I appreciate it).

Comment: Ok, that is some additional facts. I **ALWAYS** have something important planned for my holidays - at least officially ;)

Comment: This is my first time applying such a long leave, as I am quite busy too off-work volunteering for something, I don't have much time planning it right now. Most likely I would do it next month (the original plan)...

Answer (score 0):

> Should I try sending the letter to the director, and hope for the
>   rest?

If you **really** need a month off, then write the letter/email and hope for the best.  If 2 weeks is enough ( *2 weeks is a long time* ), then consider just taking two weeks.  You seem to like this job, and the people you work with and that is worth a lot.  I am not sure that taking a month off is worth risking this job.

> Or shall I just resign straight away?

This is really a **bad idea**.  If you feel strongly enough that you need a month off and are not granted it, then take the two weeks and start your job search after.  Remember, its always easier to find a job in my experience if you currently have one.

Comment: two weeks is really nothing... if you are in the workforce long enough, you should know if u have a week off from work you would end up taking the week to run errands instead of resting.

Comment: plus you might need to make urself available for help because they are still gonna find you for work-related stuff at random times.